# Method for creating any involutive permutation

Tags: permutation

The Fisher-Yates shuffle can produce any permutation of a set of $n$ elements. Is there anything that can do the same for creating an involutive permutation of $n$ elements where $n$ is an even number? This could be used to create involutive S-boxes.

Comment: Possibly relevant work: [Constructing Psuedo-Random Permutations with a Prescribed Structure](http://slideplayer.com/slide/5195019/)

Answer (score 2):

The Fischer-Yates shuffle can be used to generate random (*i.e.* uniformly distributed) permutations. As mentioned in the comments, generating "any" permutation is trivial.
So I'll make the assumption that you want an algorithm to generate random involutions on $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, such that each involution has equal probability.

It is easy to see that any involution $\pi \in \mathrm{Sym}_n$ is the product of disjoint transpositions (*i.e.* all cycles have length at most two). This observation leads to the following simple strategy to generate random involutions: ($I_n$ below denotes the number of involutions on $n$ symbols)

Choose $1$ to be part of a one-cycle (with probability $I_{n-1} / I_n$) or a two-cycle (with probability $1 - I_{n-1}/I_n = (n-1)I_{n-2}/I_n$), *i.e.* $\pi(1) = 1$ or $\pi(1) = j$ such that $\pi(j) = 1$. In the former case, one can continue in tail-recursive manner by sampling an involution from $\mathrm{Sym}_{n - 1}$. In the latter case, choose $j \in \{2, \ldots, n\}$ uniformly at random and sample an involution from $\mathrm{Sym}_{n - 2}$ (again, recursively).

An important detail in the procedure above is how to sample with probability $I_{n - 1} / I_n$. It's probably best to precompute these probabilities and store them in a table.

I'm sure many references could be found for this simple method. For instance, the procedure above (with minor differences) can be found in Algorithm 9.4 of [Jörg Arndt's thesis](http://www.jjj.de/pub/arndt-rand-perm-thesis.pdf). An implementation in C++ can also be found there.